# PHP Regex: parse data from complex text file

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP and regex how can I extract data from text file as shown in the highlighted parts (as an example but the idea is to extract the whole file):

[image]

I would like to put the highlighted parts (SHORT DESCRIPTION, LEN, TYPE, Description, SAS Name and VALUES if they exist) into a multidimensional array:

```
$columns = [
    [
        'Provider Category Subtype Code',
        2,
        'VARCHAR2',
        'Identifies the subtype of the provider, with..and SNFs.',
        'PRVDR_CTGRY_SBTYP_CD',
        [
            '01' => 'Short Term',
            '02' => 'Long Term',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'Provider Category Code',
        2,
        'VARCHAR2',
        'Identifies the type of provider participating in..Medicaid program.',
        'PRVDR_CTGRY_CD',
        [
            '01' => 'Hospital',
        ],
    ]
    // rest of the columns..
];
```

So far I have this:

```
// For real file content
$str = file_get_contents('https://data.cms.gov/api/views/i4jy-dtss/files/8331bd77-e02d-42a1-b4a4-b4a3ef31655d?download=true&filename=POS_OTHER_LAYOUT_SEP17.txt');

$fileArray =  explode("\n", $str);

// Prepare columns
$columns = [];
$column = [];

// sets the start of a new column
$startOfNewColumn = false;

foreach ($fileArray as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^\s{3}\S/m', $line) && !preg_match('/^\s{3}SHORT DESCRIPTION/m', $line)) {
        $column = [];
        $startOfNewColumn = true;
    }
}
```

This is [the regex](https://regex101.com/r/peW2RN/4) I am using.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/peW2RN/3

Comment: Why use regular expressions when you have a fixed format file? Just use SUBSTR().

Comment: @Tom It is not a fixed format as some columns have different length

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. Your Regex extracts only fields which start with Provider Category. Is it possible to extract other ones like Services: Housekeeping On-Site Residents Indicator 1: https://regex101.com/r/peW2RN/4

Comment: You have fixed length fields, it is just that you have different types of lines. So first determine which type of line you are reading and then split it using substr().

Comment: Thanks but substr() requires both start and length: which I don't know because it is varying.. regex is the tool because there's a pattern in the file but my regex knowledge is not that advanced

Comment: Add alternatives to the first group, like `(pattern1|pattern2)`

Answer (score 0):

Since this file doesn't have a "fixed" structure/pattern, It is useless to parse it with regex.

The final solution I did was to use a bunch of if else statements and loop through each line. It is not the best optimal thing to do but this is how I solved this question.